How to do calculation in SQL BigQuery?
I have a dataset of an e-commerce company. I am trying to solve the following question in BigQuery:

Get the % increase in the cost of orders from year 2017 to 2018 (include months between Jan to Aug only)

The payment_value is a column in the payments table which represents the cost of each order, and the order_purchase_timestamp  is a column in in orders table representing the date on which the order was purchased and payment was done. Data type of order_purchase_timestamp is timestamp.
order_id column is common between the two tables. order_id is the primary key in the orders table and a foreign key in payments table.
I wrote following query:
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.order_purchase_timestamp) AS purchase_year,
    SUM(p.payment_value) as total_cost_of_orders
FROM
    `scaler-sql-biz-case-2459.Target_Data.payments` AS p    
INNER JOIN
    `scaler-sql-biz-case-2459.Target_Data.orders`   AS o     
        ON p.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.order_purchase_timestamp) BETWEEN 1 AND 8 
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.order_purchase_timestamp) IN (2017, 2018)
GROUP BY 
    purchase_year
ORDER BY
    purchase_year

Firstly I joined two tables using the order_id column. Then in the WHERE clause, I filtered to get the desired rows. Then in GROUP BY I grouped all the rows according to purchase_year which I calculated using EXTRACT().
Finally I calculated the SUM(payment_value) using aggregation function.
I arrived at the following result. But I do not know how to proceed further.
Please guide me or suggest an alternate approach. Thanks in advance.
The output table is in this screenshot:
Output table
